# Why Jenkins sometime delete all builds?

Tags: jenkins

I configured new "free-style software project" Jenkins's job. It's run by polling SCM Perforce about 10 times a day. After 1-2 days all builds disappeared.

I've try to configure "Delete old builds" and "Build keeper" plugin. But nothing helps.

Probably you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's a [reported Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15156) that matches your symptoms (and it just bit me as well). The workaround (which was successful for me) is to go to **Manage Jenkins** and **Reload Configuration from Disk**.

Comment: And in cases when command line is preferred over UI, same can be done using command line: 
`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://my-jenkins-host:8080/ reload-configuration`

Answer (score 4):

Simple restart of Jenkins solve the same problem for me. Builds just appeared in Build History section.
Jenkins version I have 1.498.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Jenkins are you running?

On version 1.499, when I create a Freestyle project there is a tick-box called "Discard Old Build" with the following documentation:

> This controls the disk consumption of Jenkins by managing how long you'd like to keep records of the builds (such as console output, build artifacts, and so on.) Jenkins offers two criteria:
>
> Driven by age. You can have Jenkins delete a record if it reaches a certain age (for example, 7 days old.)
>      Driven by number. You can have Jenkins make sure that it only maintains up to N build records. If a new build is started, the oldest record will be simply removed.
>
> Jenkins also allows you to mark an individual build as 'Keep this log forever', to exclude certain important builds from being discarded automatically. The last stable and last successful build are always kept as well.

Finally, have you considered that it might not be Jenkins deleting your files? Perhaps someone setup a cron process to purge out old files? This is not unusual if you're on a shared server that might have blown its disk volume at some stage in the past.

Comment: Version of Jenkins is 1.498. I read this documentation and cannot understand why behavior is different :)

Thanks for 'cron'-idea. I inspect /etc/cron* and `crontab -e` - nothing interesting found...

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
I also have similar issue where the build history of  5 days back old builds have been lost automatically and my jenkins version is 1.530 not able to recover old build history by restarting jenkins.

Solution:

In jenkins Configure the job  there a check box called Discard Old Build is enabled under that there is log rotation where you can see Discard Old Build and  Max builds to keep options i gave 50 for both text box and restarted jenkins it working fine and recovered old build history.